# BIND as a DNS server host command is refused

Tags: dns, hostname, bind, domain

I am attempting to run my host machine as a DNS server, it will also function as the gateway.

My **/etc/named.conf** is as follows:

```
    options {
    directory "/var/named/";
    allow-query {127.0.0.1; 192.168.64.0/24;};
    forwarders { 192.168.48.2; };
};
zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "named.localhost";
};
zone "huh.dod" {
    type master;
    file "mydb-huh-dod";
};
```

My **/var/named/mydb-huh-dod**:

```
$TTL    3D
@       IN      SOA     host.huh.dod.      hostmaster.huh.dod.(
            2018042901       ; Serial
            8H      ; Refresh
            2H      ; Retry
            1W      ; Expire
            1D      ; Negative Cache TTL
);
@       IN      NS      host.huh.dod.
host    IN      A       192.168.64.1
```

I set my hostname as  host and configured domain name through the **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0** file SEARCH parameter:

```
DNS1="192.168.64.1"
IPADDR="192.168.48.10"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
GATEWAY="192.168.48.2"
SEARCH="huh.dod"
```

so the **/etc/resolv.conf** looks like:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search huh.dod
nameserver 192.168.64.1
```

Attempts at using the host command are refused:

```
host host
host.huh.dod has address 192.168.64.1
Host host.huh.dod not found: 5(REFUSED)
Host host.huh.dod not found: 5(REFUSED)


host host.huh.dod
host.huh.dod has address 192.168.64.1
Host host.huh.dod not found: 5(REFUSED)
Host host.huh.dod not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

I am not sure what the problem is.

Perhaps something to do with my iptables firewall?

Output of **netstat -anlp | grep 53 | grep LISTEN**

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.64.1:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/named           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/named           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/named           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      942/named
```

named is running

Comment: is named up and running? seen logs? give us the output of `netstat -anlp | grep 53 | grep LISTEN` in the question. is not a listen directive missing in your options?

Comment: Please edit the question for those outputs.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro adding `listen-on port 53 { 192.168.64.1; };` to named.conf seems to have done the trick I get the output of `host.huh.dod has address 192.168.64.1` thank you

Comment: Explore it, you have got much more interesting options in there.

Answer (score 1):

Upon a cursory visual inspection, your `options {}` section seems spartan.

It is missing inside it the `listen-on` directive as in:

```
options {
   listen-on port 53 { 192.168.64.1; 127.0.0.1; };
    .....
};
```

Without that directive, BIND won't listen on in the intended interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `netstat` output, BIND is running on the host thas IP address 192.168.64.1.

The client host, the one where the `ifcfg-eth0` file is from, has

```
DNS1="192.168.64.1"
IPADDR="192.168.48.10"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
...
```

So the DNS server address is correct, but the client's own address is 192.168.**48.10**... which doesn't match any of the values in the `allow-query` configuration option:

```
allow-query {127.0.0.1; 192.168.64.0/24;};
```

With this configuration, the BIND on 192.168.64.1 will reject any queries except ones coming from the 192.168.**64**.* network and from the BIND server host itself. The client's address 192.168.48.10 is outside the specified network, so of course it will get rejected.

If you want only this one particular client to work outside the 192.168.64.* network, this `allow-query` setting in BIND configuration would do it:

```
allow-query { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.64.0/24; 192.168.48.10; };
```

Or if you want to allow access from the entire 192.168.48.* network too:

```
allow-query { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.64.0/24; 192.168.48.0/24; };
```